# Horizontal stacked bar chart in Matplotlib/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I think my problem is easy to solve but I just cannot find a solution.

I want to make a horizontal stacked bar chart with Matplotlib/Pandas using this data. The csv-file contains the answers from a questionnaire. "Q4" contains values from 1-7. 6 and 7 are supposed to be missing values.

```
missing = {"Q4":[6,7]}
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", sep=";", na_values=missing)
```

I want to plot the value counts of "Q4" by using something like this.

```
df["Q4"].value_counts()
```

The output is this:

```
1.0    2906
2.0    1508
3.0     738
4.0     206
5.0     154
```

My plot should consist of one horizontal column showing the value counts of value 1-5 as a stacked bar.

Comment: If you want something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSWd4.png), use `df.T.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df['Q4'].plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Another option is:

```
df[['Q4']].T.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

[image]